# Use collection_select to update Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a Language Model so Devise users on my Rails 4 app can update their profile with a native language.

The relations are Language `has_many :users`, and User `belongs_to :language`.

In the registration edit file provided by Devise, I added the languages to be selected like so:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<%= collection_select(resource, :language_id, Language.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select language') %>


<div class="form-group"><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %></div>

<% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
  <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
<% end %>

<div class="form-group"><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %></div>

<div class="form-group"><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %></div>

<div class="form-group"><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %></div>

<div class="form-group"><%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>
```

I also have this in my application_controller file for Devise strong params:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :email
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :language_id, :current_password)
    end  
  end
```

This is displaying properly, but not actually updating the user.language_id field with the language they chose.

How can I get this to save their selection? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Paste the complete form please!

Comment: Sorry, I've added it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strong parameters seems fine.
It looks your User model holds the language_id, hence it's just an attribute like name, email etc.

**Your this piece of code for language selection, is not connected to the form(see f.collection is missing!)**

```
<%= collection_select(resource, :language_id, Language.all, :id, :name,
   :prompt => 'Please select language') %>

 Try using this one:
<%= f.select :language_id, Language.all.collect {|u| [u.name, u.id]} %> 

  If you are using rails 4: (better option)
 <%= f.select :language_id, Language.pluck(:name, :id) %>
```

**If you want to give priority to coding guidelines. This Language.something is going to fire database Query. So try moving this piece of code from View to Model & access by an instance variable in controller.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the application that you allow additional attributes to be updated via devise controllers.

Let's say the selected language id is set in params[:user][:language_id]. You need to do something like the following;

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :language_id
  end
end
```

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I forgot to mention I had done this. I updated the question to show it.